# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "52586380‬" at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)

Tags: java, talend, numberformatexception

I am writing a simple function that takes a string `-2739379824/2752586380‬/2286078538` , split it into 3 strings and convert each string into a Big Integer. The problem is that the conversion of the first and third string succeeds but for the second string I am getting the following error :
    Values
    `-2739379824`
    `2752586380‬`
    `2286078538`
    a :-2739379824

```
    Exception in component tJava_1 (Montant)
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "52586380‬"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
        at java.math.BigInteger.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.math.BigInteger.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

I've tried to convert the second string alone many times, sometimes I get the right output, sometimes this error and I don't understand why. This is my function :

```
        public static BigDecimal myfunction (String Value) {

            String[] Valuestring  = Value.split("/");    
            System.out.println("Values  ");
            System.out.println(Valuestring[0]);
            System.out.println(Valuestring[1]);
            System.out.println(Valuestring[2]);
            BigInteger a = new BigInteger(Valuestring[0]) ;
            System.out.print("a :") ;
            System.out.println(a) ;
            BigInteger b = new BigInteger(Valuestring[1]) ;
            System.out.println("b :") ;
            System.out.println(b) ;
            BigInteger c = new BigInteger(Valuestring[2]) ;
            System.out.println("c :") ;
            System.out.println(c) ;
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not copy paste the String value, there might be a special character hidden within. I tried your code and it gave me the error as you said. Then I tried deleting the `/` and typing it myself, this worked. May be copy paste source has a special character hidden within. And used `\\` in `split()`

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
{
    String x = "-2739379824/2752586380‬/2286078538"; // your string as it is giving the error
    Test.myfunction( "-2739379824/2752586380/2286078538" ); // I tried deleting the / and typed it again
}

public static BigDecimal myfunction( String Value )
{

    String[] Valuestring = Value.strip().split( "\\/" );
    System.out.println( "Values  " );
    System.out.println( Valuestring[0] );
    System.out.println( Valuestring[1] );
    System.out.println( Valuestring[2] );
    BigInteger a = new BigInteger( Valuestring[0].strip() );
    System.out.print( "a :" );
    System.out.println( a );
    BigInteger b = new BigInteger( Valuestring[1].strip() );
    System.out.println( "b :" );
    System.out.println( b );
    BigInteger c = new BigInteger( Valuestring[2].strip() );
    System.out.println( "c :" );
    System.out.println( c );
    return null;
}
```

Comment: `String.strip()` will not work with the invisible unicode character because it is not treated as whitespace. It only works because you manually removed the special character before the slash. See my solution.

Comment: Escaping the slash is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

*@Klaus* said:

> Do not copy paste the String value, there might be a special character hidden within.

In this case it is true. In your string between `0` and the second `/` there is one non-printable unicode character `U+202C` (`"\u202C"` as a Java string). It is used for [bidirectional text control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_control_characters#Bidirectional_text_control) (some languages are written from right to left).

Just put your cursor to the beginning of the copied text, then move it to the right via cursor key and after the ending `0` of the second number you will see than one time the cursor does not seem to move (but in fact it is moving invisibly). There you could also delete the invisible character, fixing your program.

---

**Update:** Here is a short version which works even with the special character still contained in the string. It uses `.split("[^0-9-+]+")` in order to split by anything in between integer numbers (plus/minus for positive/negative numbers are also treated correctly) instead of just by slash (`/`).

```java
package de.scrum_master;

import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Dummy {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Arrays
      .asList("-2739379824/2752586380‬/2286078538".split("[^0-9-+]+"))
      .stream()
      .map(BigInteger::new)
      .forEach(System.out::println);
  }
}
```

Console log:

```
-2739379824
2752586380
2286078538
```

I think you can take it from here and adjust it to your needs. BTW, I agree with Klaus that you should rather make sure your input strings are clean than having to clean them up manually. But if your strings are e.g. scraped from a website, you better use a solution similar to mine in order to make really sure that the program works as expected. Never trust data from external sources.